# Python subprocess.Popen() is not starting the subprocess properly

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a python test that startes a tcp server as subprocess.

```
def test_client(self):
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
            proc = subprocess.Popen([f'{self.bin_output_path}/CaptureUnitHalServer'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        else:
            proc = subprocess.Popen([f'{self.bin_output_path}/CaptureUnitHalServer'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        
    hal_access = HalAccess(port=12309)
    hal = CaptureUnitHal(hal_access)
    response = hal.test_scratch(TestScratchReq([1]))
    assert TestScratchCnf(verdict=True, return_value=5) == response
    print(f"\nRESPONSE: {response}\n")
    # The first proc.communicate waits for the subprocess to finish. As the server runs forever a TimeoutExpired
    # error is thrown the second proc.communicate in the exception handler get stdout and stderr from the server
    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=2)
        print(f'{outs.decode()}\n')
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    print("CaptureUnitHalServer stdout:")
    print(f'{outs.decode()}\n')
    print("CaptureUnitHalServer stderr:")
    print(f'{errs.decode()}\n')
```

The `hal` is a simple tcp client that sends a test request (TestScratchReq) to it and receives the response.
In linux this works perfectly fine. But when I run this in windows The code blocks forever at the line `response = hal.test_scratch(TestScratchReq([1]))`.
This line calls

```
def send_and_receive(self, request: str) -> str:
        self._send(request)
        return self._receive()
```

and blocks in the socket.recv() call in self._receive()

```
data = self._socket.recv(1024).decode(encoding=self.MESSAGE_ENCODING) # blocking
```

So it seems like the server is not started properly as a subprocess in windows when calling subprocess.Popen().
The following command shows the port as listening however:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | grep 12309

0.0.0.0                             12309     0.0.0.0                             0          Listen
```

I have a second implementation that is also working on windows:

```
def test_client(self):
    daemon = Thread(target=self.server_thread, daemon=True, name='HalServer')
    daemon.start()

    hal_access = HalAccess(port=12309)
    hal = CaptureUnitHal(hal_access)
    response = hal.test_scratch(TestScratchReq([1]))
    print(response)

    assert TestScratchCnf(verdict=True, return_value=5) == response
    daemon.join() # wait for daemon timeout

def server_thread(self):
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        result = subprocess.run([f'{self.bin_output_path}/CaptureUnitHalServer'], timeout=5, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    else:
        result = subprocess.run([f'{self.bin_output_path}/CaptureUnitHalServer'], timeout=5, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    print(result.stdout.decode())
    print(result.stderr.decode())
    pass
```

But it seems overcomplicated to me to have another Thread just to start the blocking subprocess.run call that throws a TimeoutExpired error after 5 seconds. A problem with this solution is also that I don't get the stdout and stderr of the subprocess respectively the following two lines of code don't print anything as the Thread is killed by the exception before it reaches these lines.

```
print(result.stdout.decode())
print(result.stderr.decode())
```

EDIT:

My question is: Why is the windows version in the first version of the code blocking? How does subprocess.Popen() differ between linux and windows? Is the subprocess not started properly in the windows case?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: My guess is that `CaptureUnitHalServer` is not starting up properly on Windows, so rather than showing us your subprocess code, it might be more helpful to attach the code in `CaptureUnitHalServer`. Is this a `.exe` file?

Comment: When I start the server in the terminal(e.g. powershell) instead of as a subprocess, it works perfectly fine. So I'm pretty sure the server is working properly